# How to work with outputs or variables from different files in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, variables, append, output

I am working with data from some scientific measurements in .csv format, each of them corresponding to a different date.

For each of the days I begin with a DataFrame. After cleaning all the noise and doing some required adjustments, I calculate some basic statistics such as mean or standard deviation values of different values.

Now I would like to work with these statistics in a single Python file in order to create plots and tables comparing the values for the different days. The problem is, I do not know how to call them in this new file.

I am aware of the inconvenience and risks of mixing global and local variables, so I would prefer to work with the outputs instead. The problem is, I can not do it recomputing the mean of each day and variable through Pandas in this new file as it would give me the mean value of that variable before all the cleaning adjustments.

I though about creating an empty text file and appending the desired outputs (such as mean and std) of the each of the days onto that list, and using later this list to create the plot and table. Would that work? How would you recommend me to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pickling. Like you can pickle the desired dataframe and then unpickle them in some other file.

**File 1.py**

```
import pickle
df.to_pickle('abc.pkl')   #df is the dataframe with you statistics
```

**File 2.py**

```
import pickle
new_df = pd.read_pickle('abc.pkl')
```

Comment: please elaborate, give example how to use it.. don't just mention a tool